# RZZ from CNOT and RZ

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

The following should represent an RZZ gate (source: https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qaoa_maxcut.html)

[image]

How do the CNOT and an RZ compute mathematically to the RZZ?

$$ R_Z(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ CNOT = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$

The above circuit, if I understand, should result in the following:

$$ R_{ZZ}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: This technique can actually be extended to any number of qubit interactions.  E.g. $Z_1 Z_2 Z_3$ would involve a CNOT from 1 to 3, and 2 to 3, a RZ gate on qubit 3, and then mirror the CNOTs on the other side of the RZ gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $R_Z(\theta)$ operator is in reality the $I \otimes R_Z(\theta)$ operator which makes it
$$
\begin{align}
I \otimes R_Z(\theta) &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
This is because if you have to include the identity operator when looking at the overall 2-qubit system. Now you can perform the matrix multiplication

$$
\begin{align}
CNOT\left(I \otimes R_Z(\theta)\right)CNOT &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
which will give you the $R_{ZZ}(\theta)$ matrix you have written (up to a global phase).

Comment: thanks!  I missed the first step :)

Answer (score 0):

It helps to write out the matrix representation of the RXX gate you post in the beginning. First, we can easily see that

$$(I - Z_1Z_2)/2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
So looking at $R_{ZZ}(\theta) = e^{-i\theta(I-Z_1Z_2)/2}$, we can again easily see that
$$
R_{ZZ}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&e^{-i\theta}&0&0\\
0&0&e^{-i\theta}&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now, you correctly conclude the resulting matrix from the circuit above, getting
$$
R_{ZZ}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}&0&0&0\\
0&e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}&0&0\\
0&0&e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}&0\\
0&0&0&e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which you'll notice we can rewrite as
$$
R_{ZZ}(\theta)=e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&e^{i\theta}&0&0\\
0&0&e^{i\theta}&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
Giving us the same matrix as above up to some global phase differences, which we can generally ignore.